# Does the new Outlook.com have other calendars?

Tags: outlook.com, calendar

Google Calendar has an option of adding ready-made calendars like certain holidays for country/religion. I wonder if there is something similar for the Outlook.com calendar. I really want to add my holidays.

[image: Google Calendars]

Comment: Like [**so**](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XsZ_pwjyqkQ/Umgo3uy4LwI/AAAAAAAAAEI/x4wHFUEPVwk/w838-h684-no/holidays.PNG)?

Comment: No, that is for the outlook mail app. I am looking for outlook.com email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a helpful link on a [microsoft help page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/outlook/calendar-import-vs-subscribe) which directs how to do it, and link with a list of holiday calendars available